# Multiple GROUP_CONCAT statements within single MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, group-concatenation

I have a table where each record has a one to many relationship with 3 other tables (with further one to one branching) leading to many rows for each main record with many columns of duplicate information. In `PHP`, I take the result set and flatten it to a multidimensional array.

I am weighing the benefits of rewriting the query to let `MySQL` do the flattening using `GROUP_CONCAT` statements. I'd end up with one row per main record with 3 fields of concatenated data (`files`, `grades + pages`, and `categories`). I am not using any `GROUP BY` statements; I'm only using `GROUP_CONCAT` to flatten.

I've done this before for a single `GROUP_CONCAT` but am curious if this a "normal" use of the technology. I am asking from a design standards and maintainability point of view or if there are any gotchas I'm overlooking. Is it personal preference? Performance appears to be about the same.

As I see it from a programming standpoint
Benefits of `GROUP_CONCAT`:

- no duplicated data to send across the internet
- simplified processing in `PHP`: even though I have to massage the data afterwards using `explode()`, it seems less obtuse than the code I have to step through, compiling the distinct values of `file`, `grade + page`, and `category` for each record
- the query actually appears to better represent what is happening by putting the many joins  in context

Downsides:

- There are multiple columns being combined within the `GROUP_CONCAT` output, so complexity is added with delimiters and nested `explode()` statements needed in `PHP` to separate out the fields.
- If it's not broken... I've been using the code without `GROUP_CONCAT` for many years. A pain to change, but I get there eventually.

The query below is much simplified. The reason for the nested query is a calculation subquery I've removed.

Query without `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT
    g.gemid,
    g.title,
    gd.filename,
    gd.license,
    gp.grade,
    gp.page,
    gp.page2,
    gc.category,
    mg.topid,
    mg.title AS gradetitle,
    mp.license AS pagelicense,
    mp2.license AS page2license,
    mp.title AS pagetitle,
    mp2.title AS page2title
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        gems.gemid,
        gems.title,
        gp.sort
    FROM
        gems
    LEFT JOIN gempage gp ON gems.gemid = gp.gemid
    WHERE gp.grade = 1
    ORDER BY gp.sort
    ) g
LEFT JOIN gempage gp ON g.gemid = gp.gemid
LEFT JOIN mgrade mg ON gp.grade = mg.name
LEFT JOIN mpage mp ON gp.page = mp.name AND mg.gradeid = mp.gradeid
LEFT JOIN mpage2 mp2 ON gp.page2 = mp2.name AND mp.pageid = mp2.pageid AND mg.gradeid = mp.gradeid
LEFT JOIN gemcategory gc ON g.gemid = gc.gemid
LEFT JOIN gemdetail gd ON g.gemid = gd.gemid
WHERE gp.grade = 1
ORDER BY gp.sort
```

Query with `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(":",IFNULL(filename,''), IFNULL(license,''))) FROM gemdetail gd WHERE g.gemid = gd.gemid) as filelist,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(category ORDER BY sort, gemcategoryid SEPARATOR ', ')  FROM gemcategory gc WHERE gc.gemid = g.gemid) as catlist,
    (SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(",", gp.grade, gp.page, IFNULL(gp.page2,''), mg.topid, IFNULL(mg.title,''), IFNULL(mp.license,''), IFNULL(mp.title,''), IFNULL(mp2.license,''), IFNULL(mp2.title,''))) 
        FROM gempage gp 
        LEFT JOIN mgrade mg ON gp.grade = mg.name
        LEFT JOIN mpage mp ON gp.page = mp.name AND mg.gradeid = mp.gradeid
        LEFT JOIN mpage2 mp2 ON gp.page2 = mp2.name AND mp.pageid = mp2.pageid AND mg.gradeid = mp.gradeid
        WHERE g.gemid = gp.gemid  AND gp.grade = 1) as gradepage,
    g.gemid,
    g.title
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        gems.gemid,
        gems.title,
        gp.sort
    FROM
        gems
    LEFT JOIN gempage gp ON gems.gemid = gp.gemid
    WHERE gp.grade = 1
    ORDER BY gp.sort
    ) g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Can't use `,` in any of the values.
- You may need to set a larger value for the Variable `group_concat_max_len`.
- You may need `DISTINCT` inside `GROUP_CONCAT()`.
- `FROM ( SELECT ... ORDER BY )` -- The `ORDER BY` will be ignored and should be removed.  You may desire the `ORDER BY` on the outside.

These indexes may speed it up:

```
g:  INDEX(gemid,  title)
gd:  INDEX(gemid,  filename, license)
gc:  INDEX(gemid,  category)
gp:  INDEX(grade, gemid, sort)
gp:  INDEX(grade, gemid, page, page2)
mg:  INDEX(name,  topid, title, gradeid)
mp:  INDEX(name,  license, title, gradeid, pageid)
mp2:  INDEX(name,  license, title, pageid)
gems:  INDEX(gemid,  title)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for mentioning not being able to use the chosen delimiters in the data. I forgot to mention that I have control over the field data. I also appreciate the list of indexes. It hadn't occurred to me that all fields being concatenated would benefit from indexes. Why is this? I thought that only fields which are part of a WHERE, ORDER BY, or GROUP BY would benefit from indexes.

Comment: @mseifert - Search for "covering index".

Comment: Thank you! That was a huge gap in my DB knowledge. Makes lots of sense after reading about it. A bit humbling that I wasn't aware of this really, after 30 years in the industry - on and off and now designing again. Thanks for taking the time to answer thoroughly - really. I may or may not switch to GROUP_CONCAT, but the indexing will help tremendously regardless.

Comment: @mseifert - Yeah, it took me years to digest indexing enough to write this  [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)